# Vue Jest Aliases Configuration

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-cli, vue-test-utils, jest-webpack-alias

I have an error when I want to run Jest because of `moduleNameMapper` settings.

I tried several methods, but nothing changes.

To reproduce:

1. clone the repo: https://github.com/zoztorun/reproduce-webpack-alias-error
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run test`

[image: terminal error ss]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Vue CLI, you should use [`@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest`](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/unit-jest.html#installing-in-an-already-created-project), which can be added to your Vue CLI project with this command:

```
vue add unit-jest
```

This will also add a `<rootDir>/test` directory with a sample test, but that doesn't fit your project's test file pattern, which places `*.spec.js` adjacent to the source files.

To adapt the result to your project:

1. Delete `<rootDir>/test` (as it would be unused, and because it points to a nonexistent `HelloWorld.vue`)
2. Edit the `jest` config in `package.json` to be:

```js
{
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
    "testMatch": [
      "**/src/**/*.spec.[jt]s?(x)"
    ]
  }
}
```

3. Delete your `test` NPM script, since `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest` automatically adds its own `test:unit` script, which must be used instead (i.e., use `npm run test:unit`).